# How to filter this structure NSArray of multiple dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c

how can i get filtered NSArray monthwise.

I have tried below approach.
What is the best to way sort/filter this kind of structure.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"filter string" forKey:@"updated_time"]];   // you can also do same for Name key... 
    NSArray *filteredarray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(email == %@)", @"filter string"]];
```

```
[
{
    "co_user_id" = 25;
    "curr_timpestamp" = "2013-10-09 16:57:39";
    id = 81;
    status = 0;
    "story_title" = "Second Story";
    "updated_time" = "2013-10-12 05:32:13";
    "user_id" = 24;
}
{
    "co_user_id" = 25;
    "curr_timpestamp" = "2013-10-09 16:57:39";
    id = 81;
    status = 0;
    "story_title" = "Second Story";
    "updated_time" = "2013-10-12 05:32:13";
    "user_id" = 24;
}
]
```

Comment: Is the filter to be on the month value inside either of `curr_timestamp` or `updated_time`?

Comment: @DavidAtkinson - its on updated_time

Comment: why you filter by email if is not a key in the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the dates from `NSString` to `NSDate` objects, then use an `NSCalendar` to extract the month. This should help you out:

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"co_user_id": @25,
                     @"curr_timpestamp": @"2013-10-09 16:57:39",
                     @"id": @81,
                     @"status": @0,
                     @"story_title": @"Second Story",
                     @"updated_time": @"2013-10-12 05:32:13",
                     @"user_id": @24
                     },
                   @{@"co_user_id": @25,
                     @"curr_timpestamp": @"2013-10-09 16:57:39",
                     @"id": @82,
                     @"status": @0,
                     @"story_title": @"Second Story",
                     @"updated_time": @"2013-10-12 05:32:13",
                     @"user_id": @24
                     }];

// Create a basic date formatter to turn the strings into dates.
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
// Create the calendar for retrieving date components.
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
// Set the month being filtered
NSInteger month = 10;
// Filter for dictionaries whose 'updated_time's have the same value as 'month'.
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:evaluatedObject[@"updated_time"]];
    return [[calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:date] month] == month;
}];
// Print the filtered array.
NSLog(@"%@", [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NSPredicate*    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"updated_time CONTAINS '-%02d-'", 10]];
NSArray*        result = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Which takes advantage of your time formatting being fairly strict.